# Apple MDM server, iOS works fine, OS X enrollment fails with "Unexpected Error"

Tags: macos, mdm

So as many of my past questions indicate I've been working on implementing an Apple MDM service from scratch. It now works flawlessly with pretty much any iOS device we throw at it, which is nice. However when we try to enroll an OS X device, which according to Apple uses the same API, it fails miserably with an unexpected error (as apposed to excepted ones I assume).

The following 2 lines show up in the system.log:

```
Mar 18 15:33:05 dizzy mdmclient[23234]: *** ERROR *** [Agent:510] ProcessOTABootstrapPayload (Unable to receive OTA identity profile <InternalError:1>)
Mar 18 15:33:05 dizzy System Preferences[93537]: *** ERROR *** [CPInstallerUI:510] Profile installation (Device Enrollment (com.capasystems.enrollment.handshake )) (Unable to receive OTA identity profile <InternalError:1>
```

Looking through the SCEP servers logs I can see it doesn't even try to connect, before determining it can't recieve the OTA Identity profile. So I'm kind of at a loss here, I've tried troubleshooting network issues, but an iOS device on the same network works fine. I've tried using an SSL connection and a non-SSL connection. No difference.

We are using JSCEP for the SCEP server if it makes any difference. Does anyone have the faintest idea what undocumented extra infrastructure or otherwise I'm missing in order to get the whole MDM thing working on OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue for a long time, I spent waaay too much time trying to figure this out.

For me, the answer came when I was able to successfully enroll one machine (my macbook pro, my personal machine), and unable to enroll another (a mac mini). Turns out, to enroll successfully, a valid certificate with CN=com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.XXX... is required. This certificate appears to be linked to the logged in user's iCloud account, which means if you're not logged in to an iCloud account on the machine, you don't have the certificate. After I (a) logged in to a valid iCloud account and (b) attempted to enroll in our mdm solution, this certificate showed up in the login keychain and the enrollment finished smoothly.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Do I need to place the root of Apple Certification Authority in the enrollment payload please? The reason i'm asking is that i logged in with a valid icloud user on my MAC OS X Yosemite but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I would double check network problems. You Mac and your iPhone can be on two different networks (wired and wireless) and in such case they can have different ports accessible on SCEP server.

Also, in the case, if your SCEP server is ssl protected (as example sitting behind Apache), make sure that your Mac has root certificate installed in System Roots.

BTW. If you have something like Apache sitting upfront of SCEP server, check it logs too.

Answer (score 0):

The error means the device is unable to retrieve the identity cert in the payload.. either point the identitycertuuid to scep payloaduuid or to the identity.p12 payloaduuid that you are including with the payload.

Comment: No it doeasn't. The question explicitly states that it works on iOS, thus there is nothing wrong with the payload. The problem is, as @UnicodeSnowman correctly pointed out, that at least some valid (at least according to the documentation) OSX devices do not have the correct certificate to accept MDM enrollment payloads unless you are logged in to iCloud.

Comment: Furthermore, as I wrote "Looking through the SCEP servers logs I can see it doesn't even try to connect, before determining it can't recieve the OTA Identity profile." so obviously it fails at some point before getting the identity certificate. This makes sence if it is rejecting it because it's lacking the correct apple root certificate.